# How Can I Open the Transportation Stop Info Popup in the New Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

In classic Google Maps, when clicking on the symbol for a public transportation stop (e.g. a metro stop, or a bus stop), a popup would open that would show the name of the stop, a link to the website of the transportation company, and any transportation lines serving that stop at a glance.

Some examples of what this used to look like:

- [*Pino Suárez* in Mexico City](http://static.betazeta.com/www.fayerwayer.com/up/2009/01/metrocddemexicogooglemaps.jpg)
- [*23RD Street - 7 Av* in New York](https://sromalewski.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/12_23rd_7th.png?w=300)
- [*Karlsplatz (Stachus)* in Munich](http://www.tramgeschichten.de/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/strasenbahnen-ab-dieser-station_munchen_google-maps.png)
- [*Broadway Bet Terrell Rd & Elizbath* in San Antonio](http://www.therivardreport.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Bus-Icon.jpg)

In the new Google Maps, it seems that clicking on such a symbol places the map marker at that location. The name of the stop and the link to the transportation company website are shown in the info box in the top left of the screen, but **where can I find the list of transportation lines serving the stop?**

Here is what I am seeing for the stops and stations listed above:

**Mexico City:**

[image: Mexico City]

**New York:**

[image: New York]

Note how in this case, even the station name seems to be less accurate than before, as there are several metro stations along 23rd Street. The stop used to be named *23rd Street - 7 Avenue* before, which I presume to be more correct than the new *23rd Street [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH82J.png)* or just *23rd Street*.

**Munich:**

[image: Munich]

**San Antonio:**

[image: San Antonio]

I am using Firefox 37.

Comment: In NY, I get the list of lines.  Can you show me what you're seeing?

Comment: @dsolimano: I have added some screenshots of what it looks like now, as well as some links to images of what it used to look like earlier.

Comment: That's so strange.  In English, I get icons of the actual train lines in that same box.  I wonder if this is a particular bug of German google maps, or only English has the feature.  Let me add a link to what I'm seeing.

Comment: It works for me in Spanish and German too, exactly as I see it in English.  This is a maddening problem.